# How to run an .exe from PowerShell with parameters from user input?

Tags: powershell

I need users to enter a computer name then have PowerShell execute an app with  the computer name as a parameter.

So I am brand new to PowerShell and have very limited knowledge with scripting (starting some classes in next couple of weeks). I need to create a script that prompts a user to enter a computer name that is on the domain and have that input run an app via this final output. "app.exe /remote \ComputerNameUserEntered"

please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Get user input with "Read-Host".

```
$computer = Read-Host "Please enter a computer name."
"app.exe /remote \$computer"
```

Comment: This will only output the string in double quotes, not run the app, prepend with the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-5.1) `&`

Comment: Thanks Clev you got me almost there. Yes @LotPings you finished this for me. The below modified is what worked for me. thanks again!

    `code` & app.exe /remote \\$computer